# Adding the new images loaded through ajax to opened lightbox pop-up

Tags: lightbox2

i am facing a issue.
I have created a images gallery in which the 18 images are showing by default and if user scroll down to the end of page then more images are adding to the gallery through ajax.

Now suppose when user have 18 images and he opens a lightbox then the opend lightbox has 18 images that he can navigate back and forth.

Now if user scroll the page to end the new images are added to the page and i want to add those images to theopened lightbox.

Please suggest a way to acheive this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific in your question. What the code looks like? What have you tried and what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

**Background**

When the user clicks an image, the Lightbox script's `start()` method is called. This will compile the list of images to show, either a single one, or a set if `data-lightbox` is specified, by going through the page. These are stored in a an array called `album` on the lightbox object.

If you dynamically load images, then the user click an image to open Lightbox, things should work as expected, as the compilation of images happens on *open*.

**Solution**

In your scenario, the Lightbox is already open, and I'm assuming you have a set of images being browsed. You want to let the user continue scrolling while the Lightbox is open and this scrolling will dynamically load more images onto the page that are part of this set.

There is no documented way of doing this. But, you can fix your issue by digging into the internals pretty easily. This is normally not recommended, but no major changes to the Lightbox2 API are expected, so this should be safe (no guarantees though).

On scroll, once new images are loaded, add them to the Lightbox object's `album` property manually. Then call `updateDetails()` to refresh the UI.

```
lightbox.album.push({
  link: 'fruit-roll-ups.jpg'
});
lightbox.updateDetails();
```